# Surface of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, 3d, surfaces

How can I find the surface represented by the polynomial $$x^2-y^2-2xz=0$$
any clue please??
I have tried to plot it using Maple

Comment: Wolfram alpha says it is an infinite elliptic cone: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2-y%5E2-2xz%3D0

Answer (score 2):

This is a [quadric surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric), degenerate because it has no constant term.  The corresponding matrix
$$ \pmatrix{1 & 0 & -1\cr
            0 & -1 & 0\cr
           -1 & 0  & 0\cr} $$
has eigenvalues $-1$ and $(1\pm\sqrt{5})/2$, two negative and one positive.  So it is an elliptic cone.  A parametrization is
$$ \eqalign{x &= (1+\sqrt{5}) (\cos(\theta)-1) r\cr
            y &= (1+\sqrt{5}) 5^{1/4} \sin(\theta) r\cr
            z &= \left((3 + \sqrt{5}) \cos(\theta) + 2\right) r\cr} $$
And here's a picture:

[image]

Of course this is only part of it: the cone extends infinitely in both directions.